# DoEvents in Excel Mac 2011 VBA for Shape Animation Doesn't Work

Tags: vba, excel, animation, doevents

I'm trying to make an animation of a point moving horizontally, representing the solution of an differential equation that represents a nonlinear dynamical system. I'm using a shape (a small oval to represent the point), and my idea is to update the position parameters of it making use of a waiting function (which I know does work, taking the real elapsed time steps from the equation solution) and I'm having problems because the position of the shape is not updated through the multiple list of values during all the macro execution, only showing the last position in the list. I'm spamming the DoEvents for enforcing screen updates. But is not working for some reason. I'm using OS X El Capitan.

I've seen a video in the web of someone demonstrating the use of almost the same code, working wonders: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fh5yBE6Moo

Even something as simple as the following will not work as expected:

```
DoEvents
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Moving Point").Left = MyZero
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Moving Point").Top = VertRef
DoEvents
timeout (1)
msgbox("Updated.")
```

The msgbox will show FIRST, and then I would see the point set at its zero position, when the macro ends. timeout is my waiting function, which I have already tested, and works well (even more DoEvents spamming, by the way):

```
Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Dim Start_Time As Double
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub
```

Is this really meant to work in such conditions?
Thank you in advance.